# Algorithm Challenge Platform

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering if there is a platform with many algorithm problems in which people can share their solutions, and to attribute a score to each one, something like speed running games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout [Hakerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms) or [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/)